# different behavior for git fsck

Tags: rhel, git

I have two servers which I'm running the command `git fsck` on specific bitbucket repository.
in both servers, I'm getting this output:

```
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
error: object directory /XXX/XXX/XXX/XXXX/XXX/objects does not exist; check .git/objects/info/alternates.
error: HEAD: invalid sha1 pointer fda39345603cdbab032ac57635405fc90d827f3c
error: refs/heads/master does not point to a valid object!
notice: No default references
```

however, when running `echo $?`, one of them returns 0 and the other returns 2. how is it possible?

Comment: Same versions of git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @vonbrand in a comment, it was a git version issue. once I upgrade it, it was aligned.

another issue was the structure, I had to create a similar structure with soft link to get rid of those errors.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/327485)

Comment: @αғsнιη thank you for tackling the review queues! Note that vonbrand only commented -- there are no other answers.

Comment: Tnx, it was 50% of the problem. The other 50% related to the structure. I will share the full solution later